# ViewStack height problem

Tags: apache-flex

I have 2 VBox containers inside a ViewStack and the viewstack is inside HBox, I've set both the height and width of the vboxes to 100% and the same for the viewstack.
My problem is that the viewstack does not display the whole content of the container childs only a part of it and displays a vertical scroll, although the width is stretched to fill the whole width of the container hbox, why doesn't the viewstack stretches to show the 100% height of its child and does it for the width only?

The main application contains the HBox which contains a module loader control which loads the module that contains the viewstack

Main Application:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" verticalScrollPolicy="on"
        xmlns:custom="components.*">
        <custom:RepeatingImage source="images/up_bg.gif" width="100%" height="100%" repeatX="true" repeatY="false" />
        <mx:Canvas width="100%">
            <custom:header id="header" />
            <mx:HBox id="content" horizontalGap="12" width="100%" x="12" y="180">
                <mx:ModuleLoader id="contentModuleLoader" width="100%" />                           
                <custom:sidead />
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:Canvas>
        <custom:footer id="footer" />
    </mx:Application>
```

The Module:

```
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:custom="components.*" width="100%">
<mx:LinkBar dataProvider="stack" />
<mx:ViewStack id="stack" width="100%">
<mx:VBox id="Content" label="First View" width="100%">  
        <mx:Canvas width="100%">
            //controls here
        </mx:Canvas>

        <mx:Canvas width="100%">
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:VBox width="100%">
                    //more controls and containers
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox label="Second View">
 //controls
</mx:VBox>
</mx:ViewStack>
</mx:Module>
```

Comment: Can you post some example code? the lines setting the width and height of each component should be all we need.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried with the `resizeToContent` property of the viewStack?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that it would help to see code, but it sounds like to me like the `HBox` may be the constraining UI element--make sure that its size is large enough to not require the scrollbar in the `ViewStack`.

You can often diagnose issues like this using `backgroundColor` and `backgroundAlpha`, or by pulling in [FlexSpy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

> why doesn't the viewstack stretches to
>   show the 100% height of its child and
>   does it for the width only?

I should have caught this yesterday. Setting anything to 100% makes it fit the parent container, not the children. I tried following your code and must admit I get lost in it. I'm pretty sure that the problem exists above your viewstack though (in the parent/children relationship, not necessarily in the code order)

Comment: no the problem is not above the viewstack, coz before I added the viewstack there was only the 1st vbox and all its content was visible but when I needed another view for this module I added the other vbox and enclosed both in the viewstack and once i did this, only a quarter of the 1st vbox is displayed and there's a scrollbar, if i remove the viewstack all the vbox controls are displayed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the padding property?

Comment: modifying the padding of what?

Comment: Padding of the viewstack and of the V/HBox

Answer (score 0):

There's an attribute "resizeToContent" in the ViewStack that you can set to true.  That should do what you want.